# Should I install the Intel Management Engine Components and Intel Chipset Device Software?

Tags: drivers

I did a fresh install of Windows 10 on My Latitude E6440, Should I install the following:

- Intel Chipset Device Software
- Intel Management Engine Components

??

There are two options for **Intel Management Engine Components** on Dell's website:

- Intel(R) Management Engine Components Installer - vPro
- Intel Management Engine Components Installer

which one of these should I install ? I am not interested in remote management.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IME does not permit or involve ordinary remote management. You need to be in a big company with resources to do core laptop management services.

So yes, for your system and the system's Driver Update App, install IME as it suggests. You can install both and also if there the IME Software (which again, is not remote management).

It is firmware so it will update during a restart.

I have IME firmware on my computers here and there are no issues with installing IME.

Comment: For IME, Should I install the Vpro version or the ordinary one ? Should I also install the Intel Chipset Device Software ?

Comment: If you have a system that support Vpro and Hardware Virtualization, you can use the Vpro version. Check your Dell hardware and also use the one the Driver App suggests. I would be guided by that.

Comment: My E6440 supports vPro, but will I ever need it ?

Comment: That depends on uses in the future but no issues installing I use virtualization because I run virtual machines. I am posting this from my Kali VM.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel Management Engine Interface drivers are required to install an ME Firmware update, at least on my ASUS motherboard. I'm not aware of any other reason for a home user to install these drivers, but installing ME security updates is probably a good idea even for a home user.